# R Trouble saving plot to image - cannot copy from the null device

Tags: r

I’m having trouble saving a plot to an image file.
I’ve the following code. The data source is not the same that I’m working but the point is the same.

```
test <- function(){
  data(diamonds)
  qplot(x = price, data = diamonds, xlim = c(0, 19000), binwidth = 100)
  dev.copy(jpeg, filename = 'imag.jpg')
  dev.off()
}
```

If I run 'test()' on the console, I get the following message:

```
Error in dev.copy(jpeg, filename = "imag.jpg") : cannot copy from the null device
```

But, if I run each line of the test function individually and sequentially, the image will be saved successfully.

It's important to mention that in both cases, before I run the code, I have cleaned previously created plots in R-Studio.

I don’t know if I’m saying something thoughtless but it seems that when the plot is created inside a called function, it requires something else that I can’t figure out.

Comment: Yes, plots don't print inside functions. You need to explicitly `print` them by `print(PlotObject)`

Comment: And, with ggplots, the better way to save them is with `ggsave`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ggplots, you're better of saving them with `ggsave`.

```
test <- function() {
  my_plot = qplot(x = price, data = diamonds, xlim = c(0, 19000),
                  binwidth = 100)
  ggsave("imag.jpg", plot = my_plot) 
}
```

If you don't like this, then, as SenorO says, you can `print` the plot:

```
test <- function() {
  my_plot = qplot(x = price, data = diamonds, xlim = c(0, 19000),
                  binwidth = 100)
  print(my_plot)
  dev.copy(jpeg, filename = 'imag.jpg')
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: I'll user the 'print' function, it seems a more generic aprouch.

Thank you guys very much.